# My employer moved me onto a new payroll. Do I need a new employment contract?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

My boss has moved me onto the payroll for one of his other companies and I am trying to find out if I need a new employment contract.

I was employed for a new start-up of his which did not work out and he has since moved me to the payroll for one of his other companies that I had been doing some work for and am now full time.

I am in the process of looking for a new flat and have been told I may need to provide a copy of my employment contract so I am trying to pre-empt and get documents together, however, my original contract does not match my current payslips.

Secondly, if I do require a new contract. My original contract has the following clause - should I ensure that this clause states that my previous employment counts towards this employment?

> 1.2. No employment with a previous employer counts as part of your period of continuous employment with the Company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK, you would need a new contract, because the old company will not be able to pay you and will possibly cease to exist, but that contract must not put you at any disadvantage. Basically, all terms would have to be the same, and the time at the previous company *would* have to count as continuous employment.

Comment: Thank you gnasher - answers my question. Much appreciated.

Comment: It’s worth noting here that TUPE regulations might apply.  https://www.gov.uk/transfers-takeovers